# $wp_query is returning nothing

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code in my plugin file:

```
// SET UP REWITE RULES FOR LISTING PERMALINKS //
    function my_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%listingId%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_tags', 10, 0);

function my_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^listing/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=listing&listingId=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

This idea is that I have a page called "Listing" with the permalink "listing" and I want to be able to have the listing's ID number after it (i.e., /listing/12345/)

I then have a shortcode running on the "Listing" page

```
// SHORTCODE FOR SINGLE LISTING PAGE //
function my_single_listing(){
    ob_start();
    include('templates/single-listing.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('listing','my_single_listing');
```

...and the first thing it does is try to get that listing ID with the code:

```
$listingId = $wp_query->query_vars['listingId'];
```

I've done this with other plugins I've written in the past, but in this case it's decided to not work.  In fact, if I enter the code:

```
print_r($wp_query);
```

I get absolutely nothing returned from it at all.  (All other content on the page is displaying fine though.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the whole page a blank page or is it just the print_r($wp_query); command/line? If the whole thing is a blank white page then you've probably got PHP error on the page

Comment: No, it's just where the print_r($wp_query); command is.  
If I change the line $listingId = $wp_query->query_vars['listingId'] to $listingId = $_GET['listingId'] and then add "?listingId=12345" (or whatever the ID is), then everything for the listing displays perfectly.  But for some reason, $wp_query is just completely empty (or not even set).  The page header and footer, etc, all displays fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with `$wp_query` being blank might be due to it not being accessed as a global variable. Prefacing it with a global declaration will allow it to access the global query:

```php
global $wp_query;

print_r( $wp_query )
```

The issue with the listing ID not being picked up has to do with it not being declared as a possible custom query var. WordPress requires you to declare them before it loads them into the global `wp_query` for the page (presumably for security). `$_GET` was able to access them since that bypasses WordPress and just uses it with PHP.

```php
function so_71685702_add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'listingId';

    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'so_71685702_add_query_vars' );
```

Once you've got that, `$wp_query->query_vars( 'listingid' )` should return a value.

Here's the [query_vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) hook information page, and the [get_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) hook information page which might be useful for further reading - might cover some things you'll run into based on the way you're setting up custom rewrites and query vars.

Comment: DOH!!!  You are absolutely right!  UGH!!!  I can't believe I missed that!  I've been bashing my head against a brick wall for two days over this now and I only just realised that I had, in deed, forgotten to include that one very simple little line of code at the top of my file!

Thanks!  xD